# Select username everywhere with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `selectable()` from jQuery it works just the way i want it.
But i want to go to the next step, i want it to select the message too inside the main chat.
So the text of the selected nickname will highlight too in the main chat.

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/56SkH/13/

**UPDATE**

What i wanna to do is that when Nickname is selected from users that the channelmessage automaticly is being selected from the users.

Comment: You can add jQuery UI via external resources in a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/56SkH/13/

Comment: Take a look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24034396/975520; is what are you looking for?

Comment: Try this [http://jsfiddle.net/56SkH/23/](http://jsfiddle.net/56SkH/23/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#users').selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            var user = ui.selected.id.toLowerCase();
            $('.channelmessage.'+user).addClass('ui-selected');
        },
        unselected: function(event, ui) {
            $('.channelmessage').removeClass('ui-selected');
        },
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/56SkH/23/

Comment: Thanks this works really fine. Is there a way to make it select when user is Nick Name with a space in the name ?

Comment: You can replace whitespace, for example with underscore(_) and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the selection on the element by adding the class `ui-selected` and using the [`selected`](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected) event:

```
$(function () {
    $('#users').selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            $(".channelmessage span.nickname.ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");
            $(".channelmessage span.nickname:contains('" + ui.selected.id + "')").addClass("ui-selected");
        }
    });
});
```

In the example I use the span content as contains selctor, by I have modified a bit the HTML markup like:

```
<p class="channelmessage"> <span class="nickname">Nickname2</span><span>:</span>
    <span class="message">Message</span>
</p>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LnnLT/

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/r2anR/)  - On click of each name corresponding message also selected using 'stop' property of selectable().

```
$(function () {
            $("#users").selectable({
                stop: function () {
                    $("#users li").each(function (key) {
                       $("#Nickname" +(key+1)+ "_message").css({"background":"white","color":"black"});   
                    });
                    $(".ui-selected", this).each(function (key) {

                       var index = $( "#users li" ).index( this );

                        $("#Nickname" +(index + 1)+ "_message").css({"background":"#F39814","color":"white"});

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: How do i do this with li id is posted nickname didnt mention it about that sorry it's being set in `html += '<li id="'+ data[i] +'" class="normaal">'+ data[i] +'</li>';`

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle ,please check .
Hard-coded Id has been replaced with 'this.id'

Comment: i'm trying this on my server but it wont get the Nickname: message selected/highlighted do i need to add new span names ?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to add a dummy class to each chat message, and the selector will be more efficient than searching for a name string.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#users').selectable({
        filter: "li",
        selecting: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");
            $('.channelmessage span.message.' + ui.selecting.id).addClass("ui-selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Here you have a working JSFiddle sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/56SkH/21/

Comment: On the fiddle its work good whenever try it into my code it wont work. Do i need to change class name or something i couldnt see

Comment: Take a look at the added class <span class="message Nickname1">Message 1-1</span> and the added CSS